# Google Analytics: Deletion of Android App profile

Tags: android, google-analytics

I accidentally deleted the property of my Android app on my Google Analytics account. Is there any way to recreate this property? It seems like it will only let you add a new property, which gives you a new tracking ID. Obviously, I want to use the old tracking ID because that's what the app is using, and I can't ensure that everyone would update to a new version?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately you are out of luck. You'll only be able to generate a new property, which like you mentioned will give you a new ID.

Directly from their [help article](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009621):

> Remember, too, that when you delete a profile, you also delete all data associated with that profile, and it is not possible to retrieve that deleted data.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that.